# Duplicate keyboard input after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: keyboard, homebrew, catalina

After updating to macOS Catalina – when I type, macOS will randomly repeat keypresses and sequences of keypresses.

Below are some examples of some mistypes just while writing this article:

```
macOS => macOSmacOS
Below => Below elow
Below => BelBelow 
Some => SomeSome
Some => Someome
```

macOS also duplicates Enter and control-sequences like Ctrl-C and CMD+V.

After updating to macOS Catalina, I also updated brew with `brew upgrade`, so maybe I have some odd update in there that might be causing this issue?

```
~ $ brew list
allure
ansible
apr
apr-util
argon2
aspell
autoconf
bash-completion
bdw-gc
brotli
c-ares
caddy
cmake
composer
ctags
curl-openssl
dnsmasq
doctl
fdupes
freetds
freetype
fzf
gdbm
gettext
git
glib
gmp
gnu-sed
go
graphicsmagick
htop
httpie
icu4c
jansson
jasper
jemalloc
jpeg
jq
jsoncpp
libev
libevent
libffi
libidn
libmetalink
libpng
libpq
libsodium
libssh2
libtermkey
libtiff
libtool
libuv
libvterm
libyaml
libzip
little-cms2
luajit
mariadb
mongodb
msgpack
ncdu
ncurses
neovim
nghttp2
nnn
oniguruma
openldap
openssl
openssl@1.1
pcre
pcre2
php
pkg-config
python
python3
python@2
rbenv
readline
rtmpdump
ruby
ruby-build
sdl2
sdl2_image
shellcheck
sphinx-doc
sqlite
the_silver_searcher
tidy-html5
tig
tmux
unibilium
unixodbc
webp
xz
```

I have tried multiple different keyboards. It feels like restarting the computer will make the issue go away for maybe 3 minutes and then the random key repeats start happening again.

What could be causing this and where should I be looking? I can't work like this and it's also dangerous because sometimes macOS repeats e.g. the enter-key which has already caused some confirmation-dialogs to be silently confirmed. :|

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same problem with me. In my case, single keys are repeated (not macOS -> macOSOS, but rather macOS to macccccOOS). Tried resetting NVRAM, didn't help.

Comment: I upgraded to Catalina and installed Little Snitch. Found a similar reddit thread -> https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/df4oqq/double_typing_text_on_catalina/ but the issue doesn't appear to be widespread.

Comment: After a restart which was totally unrelated to this, the problem seems to have gone away. Doesn't actually make sense, but no glitches since last night.

Comment: @IlkerMutlu I did a restart, but the it’s still happening for me!

Comment: Precisely this same issue came up after a macOS release a few years ago (I think pre-Sierra?). Apple support suggested re-installing the OS, which did not work for me. There was an update a few days later which fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This problem seems to show up most for me in GMail, although it is definitely happening in Microsoft Word too. Having said that, I have not had it occur once in the text boxes on StackExchange.

Resetting NVRAM and  SMC has no effect. Turning off auto-complete and spell-check in Apple->Sys->Keyboard doesn't help.

Just happened in this textbox. Glad to see others having the problem too.

Comment: I think I have a similar issue, but my issue only occurs with the `e` key. When I am typing I will get a repeated `e` character every so often - and only the `e` character. This definitely didn't happen before the upgrade and I am using an external USB keyboard.

Comment: I''m seeing this problem on a brand new 2019 MBP 16" that is running factory installed Catalina.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you happen to have Wacom settings/software installed? Seems that completely uninstalling all Wacom software and deleting its other files solves the issue.

Looks like doing so solved the problem for me, testing for 10 minutes and the issue doesn't occur.

Logitech settings may be a reason too.

Kudos to [rakdavid](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250733138?answerId=251408993022).

Comment: Still have logitech settings installed, removed wacom, no issues in ~6 hours of use. Looks good!

Comment: I did have Wacom drivers installed. I've done a clean install of Catalina in the meantime but that could very well have been the issue!

Comment: Great tip! I installed the latest Wacom drivers from their site (released yesterday Okt 14th) and it seems to have resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Uninstalled the Wacom drivers by following the instructions here and the problem has been gone for 24 hours: https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support?guideTitle=How-do-I-uninstall-and-re-install-the-Wacom-driver-on-Mac-OS-for-a-Pen-Tablet%2C-Pen-Display%2C-or-Pen-Computer%3F&guideId=001-670

Answer (score 2):

It seems like resetting the NVRAM has solved the issue for me: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

EDIT: Seems like only temporarily... after putting my computer to sleep a few times, the issue has resurfaced. :(

Comment: Are you using a 2016 MacBook Pro by chance?

Comment: @njha I also have this issue and I’m using a 2016 MBP, but with an external keyboard.

Comment: @njha I know what you're getting at but it's definitely a software issue. I've tried 3 different external keyboards and they all have that issue. I have a 2017 MacBook Pro.

Comment: It is happening to me as well. It is super annoying, I tried resetting the NVRAM like you suggested. It has gotten better, but the problem hasn't gone away. You'ou'd think that apple would be able to do a bit better with an update like this.............oh well

Comment: User with 2015 MacBook Pro hero here, same thing happening

Comment: I also have a 2015 MBP with this problem, which occurs whether I use the native keyboard or an external USB. Resetting NVRAM and SMC did not help. I also tried turning off the auto-complete/spell checker in Apple's Keyboard preferences, but that did not have any effect.