# Duplicated text replacement in WhatsApp application

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, applications, catalina

When I type in the WhatsApp application (only that application) with the text replacement being active, the last syllables of the word gets duplicated. But I found out that this only happens when the "replacement bubble" appears on top of the message.

Here's a gif:

[image]

I tested almost everything I could find... Reseted NVRAM, disabled repetition, tried to uninstall any Wacom Software (as seen [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371897/duplicate-keyboard-input-after-upgrading-to-macos-catalina)), and I had none installed, but nothing works.

I'm running a MacBook Pro 2019 with Catalina Installed. And this only happens in this particular app.